# What is a person I've affiliated called?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms, subject-verb-inversion

What are the right terms to define:

- A person who is an affiliate in a company, who brings to the company other affiliates
- What are the people he affiliated called in relation to him?
- What is he called by them?

E.g. Affiliate, affiliates, referer

P.S. the word *affiliate* is surely related here. I guess it's referring to each person relating to the company. I'm not sure about the inverted relation.

Comment: I'd call them *fellow employees* and him a *recruiter*

Comment: @Jim Agreed about the Recruiter. Will use Affiliates and Recruiter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jim's comment notes, "recruiter" is appropriate and simply refers to someone who "recruits". More information on the process can be found at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recruiter).

> [recruit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recruit) — to attempt to acquire the services of (a person) for an employer: "She recruits executives for all the top companies."

Answer (score 0):

'consociate' is to associate or to ally:

[1.     to enter into or bring into friendly association

— adj
2.  associated or united

— n
3.  an associate or partner][1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Consociate)

Socius is defined as an associate too